# How to get the view of BaseActivity inside Activities that extend it?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a BaseActivity which contains all the necessary connectivity change code and i implement this in all my activities.

As i want to show the user about the connectivity state using snackbar i need the rootlayout of the Activity which i think might be the BaseActivity. So i need the rootlayout in all other activities to show the snackbar.

```
    if(connectivityEvent.getState().getValue() == ConnectivityState.CONNECTED){

                Log.d("connectivity", "Connected");
    showsnackbar(rootlayout, "Internet Detected", R.color.transaction_failed);

            }else {

                Log.d("connectivity", "Not Connected ");

  showsnackbar(rootlayout, "No Internet Detected", R.color.transaction_failed);


            }
```

Comment: use
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() to get root view in any activity

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `abstract` methods. Your `BaseActivity` looks like this

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity{

protected abstract getRootLayout();
}
```

And now every `Activity` which extends `BaseActivity` has to fill out the method `getRootLayout` which you can use in `BaseActivity` to show the snackbar e.g.

```
showsnackbar(getRootLayout(), "No Internet Detected", R.color.transaction_failed);
```